# The Dependency Injection Pattern – What is it and why do I care?

Tags: dependency-injection, mvp

I want a very clear idea on dependency injection and single responsibility principle w.r.t to being used with mvp pattern.
Could anyone get me through these terms?

Comment: The question is rather vague. Do you have something concrete that you did not understand? What did you read? What concept puzzles your mind? If you answer these, it'll be far easier to "get you through these terms".

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: Earlier I read about using the Inversion of Control (IoC) principle to create classes that are easier to unit test.There, I found that the DI pattern was used to loosely couple classes from their dependencies.  It shows that dependency injection just means that a given class or system is no longer responsible for instantiating their own dependencies.  In this case “Inversion of Control” refers to moving the responsibility for locating and attaching dependency objects to another class or a DI tool.So question is-can Dependency Injection be very advantageous for doing Test Driven Development?